# ASP.NET Web API 2 ApiController.Ok() not working, causing timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

When request by client app, Timeout occurs.
I set breakpoints to check if the parameters were entered well in the controller method, and it looks fine.

Even after a while, an `System.AccessViolationException` occurs and my app crashes.

My Controller Code is here.

```
namespace REST_API_EX.Controllers 
{
    public class DeliveriesController : ApiController
    {
        private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

        [ResponseType(typeof(Delivery))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDeliveryByOrder_No(string Order_No)
        {
            Delivery delivery = await db.Deliveries
                .Where(d => d.Order_No == Order_No)
                .FirstAsync();
            if (delivery == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(delivery);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `Delivery` class look like?

Comment: Those kind of issues are often related to complex objects structures (with loop references or many nested navigation properties) that will cause big troubles when serialized in json. To exclude those kind of issues I strongly suggest you to map your return types into simpler objects with only the properties needed client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're using EF6. 
try

```
public class DeliveriesController : ApiController{
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false

// Your Code

}
```

because EF tries to load the reference but end up looping in that.